Nginx rewrite and change timestamp format
Is it possible to change the timestamp format of a rewrite URL in Nginx?
Example:
https://test.mysite.com/content/07-06-2024T12:41/https://www...etc

to a %Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S format?
Like:
https://test.mysite.com/content/2024-06-07T12:41:51Z/https://www...etc


Nginx normalises the URL by replacing // with a single /. Also, where does the 51 seconds come from?

That's just a minor miss type. It has the %S for seconds too. But that does not explain anything about the regex

I was able to do this with:
"~^/content/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})T(\d{2}):(\d{2})/(?<requestedUrl>.)$"

Which directs with:
https://test.mynewsite.com/browse/$redacted?timestamp=$4-$3-$2T$5:$6:59Z&url=$requestedUrl; 

